# In R Merging rows where a column has same value but different case

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, summary

So I have data where many values (x) have been separated because of case issue and I would like to merge all these values ignoring case and simply adding the values in the other columns (y and z)

I have a dataframe like:

```
x     y  z 
rain  2   40
Rain  4   50
RAIN  7   25
Wind  8   10
Snow  3    9
SNOW  11  25
```

I want a Dataframe like:

```
x     y   z
Rain  13  115
Wind  8   10
Snow  14  34
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could lower the caps on the first column and then aggregate.

**Option 1:**  base R's `aggregate()`

```
with(df, aggregate(list(y = y, z = z), list(x = tolower(x)), sum))
#      x  y   z
# 1 rain 13 115
# 2 snow 14  34
# 3 wind  8  10
```

Alternatively, the formula method could also be used.

```
aggregate(. ~ x, transform(df, x = tolower(x)), sum)
```

**Option 2:** *data.table*.  This also keeps the order you show in the result.

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(x = tolower(x))]
#       x  y   z
# 1: rain 13 115
# 2: wind  8  10
# 3: snow 14  34
```

To order the result, use `keyby` instead of `by`

**Option 3:** base R's `xtabs()`

```
xtabs(cbind(y = y, z = z) ~ tolower(x), df)
#           
# tolower(x)   y   z
#       rain  13 115
#       snow  14  34
#       wind   8  10
```

although this results in a table (probably not what you want, but worth noting), and I have yet to determine how to change the name on the `x` result.

**Data:**

```
df <- tructure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("rain", 
"Rain", "RAIN", "Snow", "SNOW", "Wind"), class = "factor"), y = c(2L, 
4L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 11L), z = c(40L, 50L, 25L, 10L, 9L, 25L)), .Names = c("x", 
"y", "z"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(x = tolower(x)) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
#
#      x     y     z
#  (chr) (int) (int)
#1  rain    13   115
#2  snow    14    34
#3  wind     8    10
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to preserve the `title` case as it seems like use `stringr` package for that and `dplyr` for `group_by` and `summarise`.

```
require(dplyr)    
summarise_each(group_by(df,x=stringr::str_to_title(x)),funs(sum))
```

where `df` is your data frame. This gives output as

```
      x     y     z
  (chr) (int) (int)
1  Rain    13   115
2  Snow    14    34
3  Wind     8    10
```